# C time.h wrap around

Tags: c, pointers, char, time.h

I would like to assign max possible time to a time_t variable then convert it to a string and print out the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    time_t maxTime;
    maxTime= LONG_LONG_MAX;
    char *strOfMaxTime;
    *strOfMaxTime = ctime(maxTime);

    printf("%s",strOfMaxTime);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this a class assignment (i.e. you need to do it a certain way)? I will answer this question accordingly.

Comment: I am following through book named "Expert C Programming , Deep C Secrets" by Linden. So your answer is no . I am just trying to self study.

Comment: This would be a 64-bit int, so maxTime should have been set in `maxTime=LONG_LONG_MAX`

Comment: Yes. I thought so too. I assigned exactly like you wrote.But i have a runtime error , which program stops execution as soon as i compile and run the code.

Comment: Oh. This helps a lot. Try LONG_MAX instead of LONG_LONG_MAX.

Comment: @J. This would make sense that you would use pointers because I am more c++ inclined. I just had started using gdb for this and was going to sanitize soon.

Comment: @J How stupid am i ? I will adjust the code and answer here.I will allocate the memory and update

Comment: Note: `time_t` is not specified by C to be a `long long` or even an integer.  `maxTime= LONG_LONG_MAX;` is a guess - it might be right - might not.

Comment: @MFisherKDX so since i dont have to allocate memory what can i do to solve this issue.

Comment: `==67536==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x7fff72084124 bp 0x7ffeeebb81c0 sp 0x7ffeeebb8180 T0)
    ==67536==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    ==67536==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x7fff72084123 in _st_localsub (libsystem_c.dylib:x86_64+0x55123)
    #1 0x7fff7208493a in localtime (libsystem_c.dylib:x86_64+0x5593a)
    #2 0x7fff72084aa9 in ctime (libsystem_c.dylib:x86_64+0x55aa9)
    #3 0x10106d71c in wrap_ctime (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x2071c)
    #4 0x101047e15 in main time.c:11`

Comment: @chux i am even getting the same error with INT_MAX

Comment: Still ugly but I will pull key info here: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 and 0x101047e15 in main time.c:11

Comment: @J.In i did not convert any number to string directly.I converted int64 to time then used ctime function to format time as a string.But i will check itoa() just in case for next string int conversions.Thank you

Comment: `*strOfMaxTime = ctime(maxTime);` --> `strOfMaxTime = ctime(&maxTime);`  (No * add &)  Hint: enable compiler warnings - saves time.

Comment: @chux you are best. Output is Tue Jan 19 06:14:07 2038.Can you post as an answer so i can choose working solution.

Comment: @chux thank you for your help.

Comment: @GrantGarrison thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3524633 You are very welcome! Good luck solving any future segfaults! Also, don't forget to always use the compiler flags -Wall -g -fsanitize=address!

Comment: @GrantGarrison I am on it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP's code is using `char *ctime(const time_t *timer)` incorrectly.

```
time_t maxTime;
char *strOfMaxTime;
// *strOfMaxTime = ctime(maxTime);
strOfMaxTime = ctime(&maxTime);
```

Yet simply assigning `maxTime= LONG_LONG_MAX;` is not necessary the correct way to determine the maximum time a system can handle.

Below is a trial and error method - likely with various implementation limitations.  `localtime()` returns `NULL` when `time_t` is out of range.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

time_t max_time() {
  time_t t0, t1;
  time_t delta = 1;
  time(&t0);    // now
  while (t0 != -1) {
    t1 = t0 + delta;
    if (localtime(&t1) == NULL) {  // If conversion fail, quit doubling.
      break;
    }
    delta *= 2; // 2x for  the next increment.
    t0 = t1;
  }
  while (delta) {
    t1 = t0 + delta;
    if (localtime(&t1) != NULL) { // if succeeds, update t0
      t0 = t1;
    }
    delta /= 2; // try smaller and smaller deltas.
  }
  printf("%s %lld\n", ctime(&t0), (long long) t0);
  return t0;
}

int main(void) {
  max_time();
  return 0;
}
```

Output  (Note that 17:59:59 depends on timezone and the year 2,147,483,647 is the max 32-bit signed integer.  YMMV.)

```
Tue Dec 31 17:59:59 2147483647
 67767976233532799
```

Comment: Tue Jan 19 06:14:07 2038 is the output i got with INT_MAX. I am checking what you stated.Thanks for the info.

Comment: @user3524633 Did your system report time stamps passed  
Tue Jan 19 06:14:07 2038 when you tried values like `INT_MAX + 1LL`?

Comment: I will try as soon as i can sit in front of my computer. You invoked my curiosity.

Comment: Computational note: `ctime(timer)` is equivalent to `asctime(localtime(timer))`.  The result of `locatime()` points to a `struct tm` which includes a `tm_year` member. That member must be type `int`.  So `INT_MAX` * secs/year (about 32,000,000 seconds) could be an upper bound of seconds. **If** `time_t` is a count of seconds, and 32-bit `int`, then values about 68,000,000,000,000,000 are a reasonable upper bound for `time_t` for a successful `ctime()`.

Answer (score 2):

From [C Standards#7.27.1p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.1p4)

> The range and precision of times representable in clock_t and time_t are **implementation-defined**.

First, you need to fix the issue in your program. The below statement must be giving error while compiling:

```
*strOfMaxTime = ctime(maxTime);
```

Change this to:

```
strOfMaxTime = ctime(&maxTime);
```

You can use `perror()` to get the error message for the given input - `LONG_LONG_MAX`, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    time_t maxTime;
    maxTime= LONG_LONG_MAX;
    char *strOfMaxTime;
    strOfMaxTime = ctime(&maxTime);
    if (errno != 0)
       perror ("Error");
    else
       printf("%d,%s",errno, strOfMaxTime);

    return 0;
}
```

On my setup I am getting this output:

```
Error: Value too large to be stored in data type
```

Indeed, `LONG_LONG_MAX` is invalid input.

As the standard mentions that the range of `time_t` is implementation-defined, so if I give `UINT_MAX` I am getting the output:

```
0,Sun Feb  7 11:58:15 2106
```

Comment: Tue Jan 19 06:14:07 2038 is the output i am gettin with INT_MAX.Thanks for the info.I am on it

Comment: Note that this depends on whether `time_t` is a 32-bit type (it is on your system, it would seem) or a 64-bit type (as found on many other systems).  For example, on a Mac running macOS High Sierra, `sizeof(time_t) == 8`.  However, it won't convert LONG_MAX to a `struct tm`; you have to divide by 256 before you get a conversion, and it indicates: `T(max) = 36028797018963967 = 1141709097-06-13 06:26:07 - after dividing 9223372036854775807 by 2^8`.

Comment: @jonathanleffler Did you find 2^8 by try and fail or is there a rule behind it. If so i want to learn it.Thanks for all info. Everyone been very helpful and instructive under this post.

Comment: I used trial and error. I set a `time_t` value to LONG_MAX and it failed, so I divided by 2 until it passed. It was 8 iterations.  Actually, my code was a lot like the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47769563/15168) by [TonyB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3830887/tonyb), except I used `strftime to get the YYYYYYYYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format (10 digits for the year).  On the whole, I don't think I'm going to worry about the Y10B (billion) problem (except it is Y11.4B, give or take a few million years).

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
*strOfMaxTime = ctime(maxTime);
```

This tries to assign the return value of `ctime` (a pointer to a char) to `*strOfMaxTime` a char.

Instead call:

```
strOfMaxTime = ctime(&maxTime);
```

And then check the return value of `strOfMaxTime` as it may be NULL if `ctime` fails to convert `maxTime`

Comment: Still same issue. I tried this when i first encounter the problem.

Comment: Look at what @chux said in the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    time_t maxTime;
    maxTime = INT_MAX;
    char *strOfMaxTime = ctime(&maxTime);

    printf("%s",strOfMaxTime);

    return 0;
}
```

The maximum year is 2038, and this is known as Year 2038 problem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: How does code know that `INT_MAX` is the maximum value for `time_t`?

Answer (score 1):

Numerous errors have been pointed out in other postings (assigning output of `ctime()` to `*strOfMaxTime`, `LONG_LONG_MAX`, etc).  On my 64bit Ubuntu 16.04 Linux system, `time_t` is defined as a `long int` and a `long int` is defined as 8 bytes as is a `long long int`.   However assigning  `LLONG_MAX` to `maxTime`  still causes `ctime()` to fail.  So I modified your code to get a range of what the upper limit of valid values `ctime()` will accept.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    time_t maxTime;

    maxTime= LONG_MAX;

    char *strOfMaxTime;

    strOfMaxTime = ctime(&maxTime);

    while( strOfMaxTime == NULL )
    {
        perror("ctime error");
        printf("%ld div by 2\n", maxTime);
        maxTime /= 2;
        strOfMaxTime = ctime(&maxTime);
    }
    printf("%s\n",strOfMaxTime);

    return 0;
}
```

Running it yields the following output:

```
ctime error: Invalid argument
9223372036854775807 div by 2
ctime error: Invalid argument
4611686018427387903 div by 2
ctime error: Invalid argument
2305843009213693951 div by 2
ctime error: Invalid argument
1152921504606846975 div by 2
ctime error: Invalid argument
576460752303423487 div by 2
ctime error: Invalid argument
288230376151711743 div by 2
ctime error: Invalid argument
144115188075855871 div by 2
ctime error: Invalid argument
72057594037927935 div by 2
Sat Jun 12 22:26:07 1141709097
```

Comment: Why ctime doesn't convert year field but doesnt give an assignment error.By the way thank you for your instructive answer.